Installing Python as a Python interpreter in WSL to run deep learning programs without any response
When I use WSL as a Python interpreter to run a deep learning program, there is no response and no error after running for a period of time. enter image description here
Has anyone encountered a similar situation before? I didn't do anything about the WSL Python interpreter.

Then it's time for step one: try this without VS Code to see if it's WSL, or your VS Code setup.

As first step you should try a simple hello world python script to see if python works as expected in your system. It looks like fine but it doesnt hurts to check.
Then you can try runinng your scprit just by
python  myscript.py

to do this you need to navigate to the location your scirpt is located
in your case
cd /mnt/d/Python_Project/TransUNet_baseline/train_model

This helps because in model training it is highly likely that your training script calls diffrent files and again it is highly possible that paths of those files given as relative paths. In this condition python thinks starting point of path as your current working directory.
You need to change your current working directory to your script location (with cd command given above).
This might not cause an error if files opened with write/read, python might have created those files and tried to read each data inside (in this case none)  so it cant train anything. This is just a guess by the inforamtion provided. It might be a different problem.
